# Containers crash inside structs?

Tags: c++, stl, struct, containers

I can't seem to write to std containers vector, map and multimap (only ones I've tried) when accessing them in structs.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
struct B
{
    void* pp;
};

struct A
{
    std::vector< B* > veEvents;
};
```

in a class function somewhere

```
A* d = new A;

B* f = new B;
d->veEvnts.push_back( f );  //<< this line crashes
```

Trying to access a container in this fashion crashes STD.  It crashes in the STD code on lines refencing this pointers.  I've tried several workarounds including typedef'ing the vector statement but that didn't work.  The one that seems to have promise as a workaround was putting a function inside a struct and calling the function...

```
struct B
{
   void* pp;
};

struct A
{
    void K( B* f )
    {
        static std::vector< B* > veEvents;

        veEvnts.push_back( f );  //<< this line crashes 
    }
};
```

in some class function

```
A* a = new A;
B* b = new B;
a->K(b);   //This seems to work.
```

Is there any way around the initial problem where accessing the container declared inside a struct causes an access problem?

Comment: You will have to find the stack corruption that is crashing the application in the first case. The code you pasted here should work and is not causing the problem. I guess some other piece of your code is causing the error but the application only crashes on this line. Try using valgrind to find the problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with any of the code you're showing. Please include an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: All those pointers! Yikes!

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  I appreciate them!  I am still having the issue and will keep your suggestions in mind.  I'll post back when I have something that may be more helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the complete code for class 'B' ? If yes, then there is no obvious problem in code pasted. If no, then one of the possible scenarios leading to crash could be:

1. Class B allocates memory to *pp while creating new object but doesn't do the same  while copying (i.e. shallow copy in copy constructor).
2. When you insert an object in vector, it calls copy constructor to copy your object into vector memory space. Due to shallow copy, both the object inserted and its counterpart inside vector share the same pointer pointed by pp.
3. Now the object goes out of scope and destructor deletes memory pointed by pp. Vector counterpart of this object still points to this memory and trying to access that somewhere.

When you try to do the same thing through static reference, no deletion happens (static object won't be deleted once out of scope). Both your object and corresponding object inside vector keep pointing to valid memory and no crash happens.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I tried creating a blank B struct and the issue still happens.  To me that eliminates the possibility that something about pp may be causing the issue.  I'm going to play with this some more and when I have some  more info I'll repost.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

All right!  Got to the bottom of it.  Ivaylo was right about there being stack corruption.  The pointer in question pointed to a vector on a class's member variable area.  The vector was originally created there, copied to another struct of the same struct type on the heap but the vector still pointed to the class stack.  I tried writing a deep copy but from a different class.  That didn't work.  So I created a struct on the heap from the start and used that to save variables on the first pass.  Later, in a different class, with the struct on the heap, access to the vector works.  The original struct should have been created that way in the first place.  Thanks again guys.  I appreciate  all your help.

Comment: I don't seem to have the reputation to up vote otherwise I would.